# Can we use the inheritance content in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I know that we can use template inheritance concept but can we use content inheritance?

Example:

```
content
  Home
     content1
     content2
     content3
```

**content3** have a field MyText = "Text". content1, content1 can be have MyText = "Text" by inherit content3 ?

Comment: OOTB doesn't exist such a functionality. I don't recommend to have it, your content will be a mess if you use it.

Comment: Because I have to do personalized (a sublayout - example: footer) for ALL item in my content item so can you suggest another solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not available in the Sitecore box, but there is a module available on the [marketplace](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/F/Field_Fallback.aspx) that provides field fallback. It is not mentioned to be supported on v8 but it might work.

Whether it is a good idea..  Sitecore Climber already mentioned that your content might get messy and I tend to agree with that - but I also had a customer who really needed something similar. So if your architecture requires it, you could try the module - or write something yourself.

Remember that you can sometimes also get similar results by redesigning components (creating some extra ones) and using datasources.

Comment: Exactly for personalization you have to use datasources for components not another page item.

Comment: Currently I use datasources for each component but I have do the same content one by one for multiple item in the content I think it will not good.